# Chameleon template rendering

Tags: python, templates, chameleon

I am new to chameleon templates. i paste code snippet ..

runtemp.py

```
 import os
 path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 from chameleon import PageTemplateLoader
 templates = PageTemplateLoader(os.path.join(path, "templates"))
 template = templates['mytemp.pt']
 template(name='John')
 print str(template.read())
```

mytem.pt

```
 <testtag>
       <innertesttag>${name}</innertesttag>
  </testtag>
```

But the output i got is

```
 <testtag>
       <innertesttag>${name}</innertesttag>
 </testtag>
```

I was expectinng John in output instead od $(name)
What is going wrong ? how to render template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template.read()` just reads the contents of the template; you discarded the actual rendering result. `template(name='John')` returns the rendering.

Do this instead:

```
print template(name='John')
```

Comment: But how to do this for multiple values? like name, address , phone etc.

Comment: @user1539813: add more slots to the template, and simply pass them in as keyword arguments when calling the template.